# Does not order of table creation matter in mysqldmp?

Tags: mysql

I have got a mysql database with tables having a lot of foreign dependency among themselves, For e.g. Say, There are three tables-: Student,Department,Course.
Example Scheme

```
>Department(ID,Name)
>Course(ID,Name,Dep_ID){Dep_ID foreign}
>Student(ID,NAME,Dep_Id,Course_Id) {Dep_ID, Course_id Foreign Keys)
```

So Since Course,Student are dependent on Department, The order in which I created the tables was Department, Course, Student.

When I created the mysqldmp file, the order of the table creation in the script was random. However when I tried to restore the db, it did not give me any error. Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens or works because while restoring it doesn't do the `FOREIGN KEY` checks. In your dump file you will find a comment line like below

```
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
```

Here `/*!40014 ... */` is a conditional comment. What it does is, disable the FK checks and once the dump is restored it re-enables the FK checks. See [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html)

Answer (score 3):

`/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;`

You'll find these in the headers of such files. It disables foreign key checks on versions of MySQL server newer than 4.0.14 (I think that is how the 40014 is read.)

You note at the bottom of the scripts, there is usually a similar block returning those to their previous values.